# saving stdout, stderr and both into 3 separate files

Tags: unix, shell

I am using ksh. On this link http://www.shelldorado.com/shelltips/advanced.html#redir , there is an example for saving stdout, stderr and both into 3 separate files.

```
((./program 2>&1 1>&3 | tee ~/err.txt) 3>&1 1>&2 | tee ~/out.txt) > ~/mix.txt 2>&1
```

I tried that but I am getting below error:

```
ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected
```

Please advice.

Comment: Free advice: don't use websites that talk about "advanced shell tips" that don't even tell you which shell they're talking about. They don't all have the same syntax, and someone who doesn't know that isn't qualified to write advanced tips.

Comment: ok, then can YOU tell me how this can be achieved in ksh? THAT will be real good Free advice from you.

Comment: I was able to fix it.  It is just that the space was required between the two brackets. So following is 
working correctly now:( (./program.sh 2>&1 1>&3 | tee err.txt) 3>&1 1>&2 | tee out.txt ) > mix.txt 2>&1

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much works for me:

```
$ ksh
$ ps | grep "$$"
 6987 pts/6    00:00:00 ksh
$ cat program.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "err" 1>&2
echo "out"
$ ((./program.sh 2>&1 1>&3 | tee err.txt) 3>&1 1>&2 | tee out.txt) > mix.txt 2>&1
$ cat out.txt
out
$ cat err.txt
err
$ cat mix.txt
err
out
```